# Execution order of metal thread groups

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, metal

I am trying to use metal to implement a hardware-accelerated image filter (seam carving for anyone interested) . One step involves running code row by row, with calculations for each row depending on calculations on the above row. However, the calculations for each row can be parallelized by pixels.

One approach would be to schedule the kernel once for each row, but I am sure there is a better way to do it as this would cause a lot of overhead.

Is there some way to tell Metal in which order to execute thread groups?

Comment: Are the calculations for row N, pixel M dependent only on row N-1, pixel M? Or are they dependent on other pixels from row N-1?

Comment: Metal2 has raster order groups. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/ios_and_tvos_devices/about_gpu_family_4/about_raster_order_groups?language=objc

Comment: @MoDJ Thank you, but I have already checked out the documentation on Raster Order Groups. They require annotation with a constant index.